# JavaFX BorderPane vs Pane hiding Labels

Tags: javafx, borderpane

I have a working map using Pane and Path  and Label objects. I place several Path and Label objects onto the Pane. The Path objects represent countries and the Label objects their capitals. So it shows a country and in the middle a Label with a String object bound to the Label.

```
count.textProperty().bind(system.getNations().get(nameNoSpace).getTroopCount().asString());
```

When using `BorderPane` instead of Pane the Label objects suddenly stop showing up?

Any idea what is the reason ?
Is the `BorderPane` hiding the Labels ?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the `BorderPane` come into play? How to you add content into it? Please provide the relevant code/FXML.

Comment: BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
Path nation = new Path(nameNoSpace);
MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
moveTo.setX(Double.parseDouble(parts[i]));
moveTo.setY(Double.parseDouble(parts[i+1]));
nation.getElements().add(moveTo);
...
root.getChildren().add(nation);
...
Label count = new Label();
count.setLayoutX(x);
count.setLayoutY(y);
count.textProperty().bind( system.getNations().get(nameNoSpace).getTroopCount().asString());
count.setOnMouseClicked(me -> mouseClickHandler(me));
root.getChildren().add(count);

Comment: That is unreadable. Please put the code in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add children to a BorderPane using the `root.getChildren().add(node)` method.
to add object to a BorderPane you need to use other methods such as

```
setCenter(node);
setTop(node);
setBottom(node);
setLeft(node);
setRight(node);
```

See the [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) documentation for more informations.

If you need to use the`getChildren().add()` method you can insert a Pane at the center of the BorderPane and add the nations in the Pane.

Comment: If it worked please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. This will also give you 2 reputation points. @HGOHGO